# OpenLayers - Switching to Google Basemap causes a flicker as it zooms to extent

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I created and example based off of the [spherical-mercator example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/spherical-mercator.html) example and placed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/INFOR/AT5By/).  I made the bing road layer the default.  If you zoom in on a location and then switch to a google layer you'll see the map go to full extent and then zoom to the correct extent.  It happens very quickly but it is a distraction.  I've tried several hacks to get around this but none of them work (delayed opacity, calling setMapObjectCenter before setting visibility).

Anyone willing to figure out (or already know) how to eliminate the flicker/animation?  Note that this is only an issue the first time you select a google base layer.  Subsequent switching transitions beautifully.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 13.0.1 - no jumping to extents when changing layer.

Comment: I updated to FF 13.0.1 and can witness the same flicker.  Try it a second time (click Run and try a second time).

Comment: Submitted as issue 548 - https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/548